# Excel VLOOKUP and getting data from another sheet

Tags: excel, ms-office, vlookup

I work in office Excel online at it seems it is different than "regular" office. I have a standard case of two excel sheets that contain two matching columns both A columns (starting with 2 row, first is title of row). In first sheet I need to add second column value from second sheet where values from A match. This seems easy but, for some reason in online office this simple formula does not work:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4170,2,0)
```

this gives just N/A result although matching value in Sheet2 exists.
Column is in both sheets A, with title sku in row 1. Second sheet contains additional data in column 2 (B) which I want to put in F column of Sheet1 using this formula.

Can you tell me why this doesn't work? IS office.com different in term of formulas?

Also, when I pull down this formula this A starting number in "Sheet2!$A$THISNUMBER" gets bigger, like

=VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!$A$3:$B$4170,2,0)

Comment: Most likely you've got a trailing space or something... VLOOKUP should work regardless of platform.

Comment: What is a trailing space? I need to fix this and I have no idea how.

Comment: An extra space at the end of the value in `A2`, or on the end of the matching value in Sheet2.

Comment: It is not that. I see what is the problem. On one sheet numbers from that id column are numbers aligned right, and on another sheet are obviously not seen as numbers, and aligned left. I am not sure what to do here, when I try to set them as numbers it doesn't work.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885